# pymunk verification test failing after fresh installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymunk

I tried installing `pymunk`, but the installation verification test (`python -m pymunk.tests test`) is failing with:

```
>python -m pymunk.tests test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ayrto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 185, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\ayrto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\ayrto\pymunk.py", line 4, in <module>
    space = pymunk.Space()      # Create a Space which contain the simulation
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pymunk' has no attribute 'Space' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I am running Python 3.8.3 in Win 10.

pymunk version:

```
pip install pymunk
Requirement already satisfied: pymunk in c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (5.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.13.1 in c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pymunk) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from cffi!=1.13.1->pymunk) (2.20)
```

Comment: There is a active issue in the pymunk issue tracker: https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/issues/182 Are you the same person? If not, could you add your info to that issue? Seems like this can be a widespread issue

Comment: No it wasn't me. @Aamir's answer solved it <hangs head in shame>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a local file named "pymunk.py". That's being imported instead of pymunk. Change your file name to something else.

Comment: Doh! That was the problem. I guess I learned a bit more about how `import` works. Should have thought a little more about the `circular import` hint in the error message.